# Why are elements of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ continuous?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Algebraic Geometry I by Görtz and Wedhorn. Definition 1.46 is about prevarieties:

A prevariety is a connected space with functions $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ with the property that there exists a finite covering $X=\bigcup_i^n U_i$ such that the space with functions $(U_i,\mathcal{O}_{X\mid U_i})$ is an affine variety for all $i=1,\dots ,n$.

Let $U\subseteq X$ be open and $f\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$. How do we show that $f$ is continues? We only know that $f$ is continuous if we have $U\subseteq U_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Continuity can be checked locally.

Comment: But the $U_i$s don't have to be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, then for any member $U_i$ of the affine open cover, the restriction $f|_{U \cap U_i} \in \mathcal{O}_X(U\cap U_i)$ is continuous when viewed as a map $f|_{U \cap U_i} : U\cap U_i \to \mathbb{A}^1_k$, where $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ denotes the affine line over the ground field $k$. Let $V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^1_{k}$ and observe that 
$$ f^{-1}(V) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(V) \cap U_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \left(f|_{U \cap U_i}\right)^{-1}(V)$$ is open in $U$.

Comment: So you assume the $U_i$s to be open in $X$?

Comment: If $X$ is a locally ringed space with an already prescribed topology, then the $U_i$'s must be open in $X$, by definition.

Comment: Thx. As far as I read the book the authors didn't came up with a definition of locally ringed spaces but of course $(U_i,\mathcal{O}_{X\mid U_i})$ is only defined for open sets $U_i$ by Definition 1.36. So now the continuity question is solved for me.

Comment: A locally ringed space is a ringed space, such as $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, such that for each $x \in X$ the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ at $x$ is a local ring (i.e. has a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x$). A function $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, vanishes at $x$ if and only if the germ $f_x$ belongs to $\mathfrak{m}_x$. The maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is used to define other notions, as well, such as the Zariski tangent space at $x$, but that's another topic.